# Wordpress / htaccess / Mod_rewrite - need help linking to non-wordpress script

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got a wordpress installation in the root folder of a site, and it's working just fine. I also want to add a completely seperate file - call it `whatever.php` - to the web root as well. It has nothing to do with wordpress, but the way the htaccess file is setup, it's trying to convert the link to a post page that doesn't exist.

How can i write an exception in the htaccess file that will let me link to my whatever.php script, while keeping everything else working as a default?

Comment: Check your wordpress setup, the default behaviour is that files that exist will be called - not wordpress.

Comment: posting your .htaccess file will help us help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the generic htaccess file (above), you shouldn't have any problem, since the line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` set the condition that the request url (`%{REQUEST_FILENAME}`) is not a file (`!-f`) on the rewrite rule.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

If you are using the auto generated file, you can add that condition to the chain rule definition.

More info:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: interesting. i guess somewhere down the line that functionality was removed or replaced. I just reinstalled wordpress, and things seem to be working as expected. Thanks for the input, and the links.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^whatever$  whatever.php  [QSA,L]
```